# dbDelta support for FOREIGN KEY

Tags: php, mysql, dbdelta

**On PHP 5.3.13/MySQL 5.5.21 the following code doesn't work:**

```
if($check_custom_fields_form!=1){
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ". $table_custom_fields_form ." (
                `form_name` longtext NOT NULL,
                `field_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES $table_custom_fields (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
    dbDelta($sql);
}
if($check_subscribe_cat!=1){
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ". $table_subscribe_cat ." (
                `subscribe_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                `cat_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY (`subscribe_id`) REFERENCES ".$wpdb->prefix."tgt_subscription (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES ".$wpdb->prefix."terms (`term_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
    dbDelta($sql);
 }
```

**The [code provider](http://www.dailywp.com) suggested a downgrade to MySQL 5.1.37 (no, thanks) or the following update:**

```
if($check_custom_fields_form!=1){
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ". $table_custom_fields_form ." (
                    `form_name` longtext NOT NULL,
                    `field_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                    KEY(field_id)
        ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
        dbDelta($sql);
    }
if($check_subscribe_cat!=1){
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ". $table_subscribe_cat ." (
                  `subscribe_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                  `cat_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                  KEY(subscribe_id),
                  KEY(cat_id)
      ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
      dbDelta($sql);
   }
```

Which seems like a rather dirty way to work around the problem (no cascading deletes/updates). Therefore:

1. **Do I really have to live with that [until dbDelta supports FOREIGN
   KEY](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19207)?**
2. **Is it true that dbDelta only works with foreign key in a 3 year old MySQL version?**

Comment: While cascading deletes/updates are nice, are they totally necessary? Can you include that part in your code, or refactor your tables?

Comment: I am not sure whether they are necessary, I haven't studied this 3rd party code enough to know.

Comment: TheDeadMedic is correct. However, I just found this [Link dbDelta and FOREIGN KEY](http://www.browserstudios.com/2013/08/23/how-to-solve-the-problem-with-dbdelta-and-foreign-key/). It explains a way around the problem. It worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really have to live with that until dbDelta supports FOREIGN KEY?

Quite frankly, yes. But that's the beauty of open source - anyone is welcome to post a patch!

**However**, expanding it to cover other aspects of schema design would almost certainly incur unwanted complexity & heighten the possibility of failure - something the core team will strongly consider beforehand.

I would take @xav0989's advice - use `dbDelta` for it's intention (basic table implementation, column additions & adjustments), and handle the additional features with `$wpdb`.